# angular ui-router child state resolve overwritten by parent's

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states

```
var books = {
    name: "books",
    url: "/books", 
    component: "booksComponent",
}

var specificBook = {
    name: "books.specific",
    url: "/{Id}", 
    component: "booksComponent",
    resolve : {
        Id: ["$stateParams", getId]
    }
}

$stateProvider.state(books);
$stateProvider.state(specificBook);

function getId($stateParams){
    return $stateParams.Id;
}
```

but for some reason when i get to a url `#/books/12345` the Id received by the component is `undefined`

what is wrong? Should I specify my routes differently?

Comment: check out this one https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3256

Answer (score 0):

When you have URLs those have dynamic parts to them which are called parameters, you have several options for those specifying parameters.

```
$stateProvider
.state('books.specific', {
    url: "/books/:id",
    templateUrl: 'books.specific.html',
    controller: function ($stateParams) {
        expect($stateParams).toBe({id: "42"});
    }
})
```

**(OR)**

Alternatively, you can use curly brackets.

```
url: "books/{Id}"
```

In case of your problem, **#/books/12345**, you will have to change your url as pattern 2 **url: "books/{Id}"**, then you will be able to work as you wish.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
resolve: {
    Id: function ($stateParams) {
        return $stateParams.Id;
    }
}
```

I don't know why you would want to since $stateParams.Id can be injected into your controller and used directly. Remember, you will need to put add 'Id' to your controller function in order to use it. Cheers